# Right way to process form text for sending email in PHP

Tags: php, email, web-applications

I am currently processing a form with text and making an email out of the text.

I am facing two problems:
1) If I just take the text as is, I get \n\r that appear in the email whenever the person uses line breaks.

2) If I use nl2br() function on the input text, I get 
 strings in my email.

Is there a correct or "best practice" way handling such situations?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add appropriate headers to your email

```
// To send HTML mail
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

before using `nl2br()`

```
// Then mail it
mail($to, $subject, nl2br($message), $headers);
```

Comment: That seemed like a good idea, but when I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: One comment to help others.  The above answer turned out be correct.  The other thing that was a problem in my case was using nl2br() function in another place on that string.  Also, if other encounter this issue, try not using mysql_real_escape_string() on the string which is supposed to be emailed.